# Calculating average over a function set

Tags: functional-analysis

Non-math version of the problem: I am running with a GPS device, recording my path. I know the curve the GPS has recorded. However, the GPS device actually has an accuracy, which I can assume to be fixed (for starters).

Assuming that the curve the GPS device records is continuous and that the actual curve is also continuous (as I do not possess the power of teleportation :) how can I calculate the expected length of my run?

Now, I can translate the problem in math terms: I am looking for the average length of a function $f:[0,T]\mapsto\mathbf{R}^2$, such that $f \in C^1[0,T]$ and $\|f-g\|_{\infty}<c$, where $g \in C^1[0,T]$ is a fixed function (the recorded data), $c$ is a constant (the accuracy of the GPS) and $T$ is the time it took me to run the distance.

However, when it comes to the solution, I have absolutely no idea. I have not studied much functional analysis, so if this is a trivial exercise, sorry. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Good question! The main issue as it stands is that the *average* length of such a function isn't really defined as it stands. There are (admittedly silly) paths of arbitrarily large length which satisfy your $\lVert f - g\rVert$ condition, and there's no particular reason why you shouldn't have followed any of them. You'd need some plausability reason to discard these, based on deciding how 'likely' a particular path is to be correct.

Comment: @Sharkos Thank you for your comment, I had not realized this. Could you read my comment below Norbert's answer, so that I don't copy it?

Comment: That definitely fixes the existence of arbitrarily long paths since length is now bounded by $VT$, though I hope this is respected by the data given. The issue I raised still stands, however. You can only have an average of something if you have some sense how likely each particular path is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were drunk your path may look like $f(t)=g(t)+c\sin(\omega t)$ for sufficiently large $\omega $. In this case your path $f$ will not significantly differ from $g$ in $\Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty$ metric, but the length of your path could be arrbitrary large. Hence you need to reformulate your problem in terms of $\Vert\cdot\Vert_1$ metric or put some restrictions on possible trajectories.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had not thought of that, not to mention in the current form, there are even non-rectifiable curves allowed. I believe that requiring a piecewise-continuous first derivative, that is bounded by a constant $V$, is sufficient to exclude pathological cases. Is this correct?

Comment: Even in this case we have only bounds for possible length's of $f$. If you really need **expected value** of the length, you need to put some probability measure on the space of all possible trajectories. Since this space is the unit ball (with center $f$ and radii $c$) in the space of piecewise-continuous functions you will have problem. Becuase there is no translation invariant $\sigma$-additive measure on the unit ball of infinitedimensional space.

Comment: At last if you really want to get expected value I suggest you finite amount of parameters. Use them to parametrize curves $f$ (you will not cover all possible, but I think you could describe sufficiently many). Put some probability measure on the space of your parameters and compute expected value.

Comment: "there is no translation invariant σ-additive measure on the unit ball of infinitedimensional space" This seems quite obvious now that it is pointed out, but could you provide a reference? Also, if I say that $\|f-g\|_1$ has a normal distribution, would that be enough for a well-defined problem?

Comment: 1. See Halmosh's Hilbert Space Problem Book, problem 12. 2. Since you have no well deined probability measure here (unexistence of "good measure" is essential property of infinite dimensions not a particular norm)